# Сужающие преобразования при инициализации объектов универсальными инициализаторами

Tags: c++

Почему при  инициализации объекта обычным присваиванием **не константного выражения**, не наблюдается сужающее преобразование:

```
 int n{ 5 };    
 double d1 = n;  //ок
```

а если инициализировать универсальным инициализатором:

```
double    d1{n};
//error: conversion from 'int' to 'double'
// requires a narrowing conversion
```

то тут компилятор выдает ошибку о сужающем преобразовании? Как на это влияет, если  инициализатор `n` является константным выражением?:

```
constexpr int k{ 5 };    
double d{ k }; //ok
```

Comment: `error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'double' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]` Думаю вот почему =)

Comment: Ну и для понятия, с `constexpr` сохранается состояние инициализатора в статической области памяти, и оттуда грузится. https://godbolt.org/z/qhKW7KdGP

Comment: @ori, определение не поясняет причину.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это

```
int n{5};
double d1 = n;  //copy-initialization
```

обычная инициализация копией ([copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)). При необходимости преобразования из одного типа в другой применяются [неявные преобразования](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), но никаких проверок того, что целевой тип сможет вместить преобразуемое значение не производится.

Это

```
int n{5};
double    d1{n}; // list-initialization
```

[list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Такая форма инициализации запрещает *сужающие преобразования (narrowing conversions)*.

К сужающим преобразованиям в частности относится преобразование целочисленного типа в тип с плавающей точкой, за исключением случая, когда преобразуемое выражение есть константное выражение, вместимое целевым типом, и обратное преобразование к исходному типу даёт первоначальное значение.

[dcl.init.list / 7.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7.3):

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
> ...
> from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type
> ...

Итак, в первом варианте list-initialization мы наблюдаем преобразование *неконстантного* целочисленного выражения в тип с плавающей точкой. Такое преобразование считается сужающим.

Во втором варианте list-initialization мы наблюдаем преобразование константного целочисленного выражения в тип с плавающей точкой. Причём исходное значение представимо целевым типом, и обратное преобразование из целевого в исходный тип даёт первоначальное значение. Такое преобразование сужающим не считается.

Comment: Такая форма инициализации запрещает сужающие преобразования, за исключением случая, когда преобразуемое выражение есть константное выражение. Это в вопросе отражается. Но вопрос в том _ по какой логике  такие правила?

Comment: Сужающие преобразования опасны тем, что исходное значение в процессе преобразования может быть потеряно. Например, `std::uint8_t x = 65535;`. Иногда такое поведение не желательно. Если целевой тип не способен вместить все значения, представимые исходным типом, то преобразование в общем случае считается сужающим. Но в случае с константным выражением потерю точности можно обнаружить на этапе компиляции и предотвратить. Если потери точности нет, то почему бы не разрешить такое преобразование?

Comment: Последние два предложения  в ответ подключить бы